# Curl equivalent code snippets for NET::HTTP in ruby

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http

The syntax for NET:HTTP seems complicated and there are very minor things that might get missed.

However curl is much older and well documented.

Is there some documentation/blog-post etc where NET:HTTP equivalent constraints for curl are published ?

eg:

To make a https request use:

```
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

How do I use curl flags like -u, -X, -H, -d in NET:HTTP ?
Any resources would be helpful.

Thanks

P.S: Its not possible to use third party gems in the environment I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-X controls the kind of request you're making. You control that by creating the request type you want, i.e.: `Net::HTTP::Post` (or `Net::HTTP::Put`, and so on).

-d sets the data, so, `request.set_form_data({"key" => "value"})`.

-u is for username (and password? i don't remember the specifics of -u with cURL), so, `request.basic_auth("username", "password")`.

-H sets a header, so, `request.add_field("header", "value")`

I usually use [this](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) as a reference when I'm working with Net::HTTP and forget something (since its pretty easy to find on Google when I lose the link.)

PS: You can always install gems to a local directory and set a custom GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH instead of using the system-provided gem dirs.